# How do I update a div on a page using Spring Boot?

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

I wanted to update my div, something like

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = springBootResponse.responseText;
```

But I cannot find a way to send plain text as a response from my controller.
How do I even do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `@ResponseBody` on a controller method?

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/sendtext")
public String sendPlainText(){

    //You can use different methods here to retrieve your String

    return "Your text here.";
}
```

Then by doing an ajax call to `/sendtext` endpoint you should be able to get what you want.